# Python3 Dictionary - Sort by date keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
  "dates":
    {
      "2020-01-01": "something 1",
      "2019-04-20": "something 2",
      "2020-03-15": "something 3",
      "2019-12-31": "something 4"
    }
}
```

Let's assume this dictionary is stored under a variable name `my_dictionary`.

How do I sort `my_dictionary["dates"]` by **date** (preferrably by a datetime format which I can define by myself)?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to sort your dictionary? Generally in most languages dicts / hashes are unordered.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. I am looping through this kind of dict and I am checking for differences between the dates' values in a loop - for this to work correctly, I need the dictionary to be sorted by date correctly.

Comment: `my_dictionary["dates"] = dict(sorted(my_dictionary["dates"].items()))`? or just iterate directly over `sorted(my_dictionary["dates"].items())`.

Comment: Previous questions/answers do mostly use Python2 (not Python3) and do not sort by dates, but they rather sort by numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3...) or by characters (e.g. 'a', 'b', 'c'...).

Comment: @Axe319 - thank you! Your solution seemed to work out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort by dates, you could convert each of the strings to `datetime` objects and sort that way:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = {
    "2020-01-01": "something 1",
    "2019-04-20": "something 2",
    "2020-03-15": "something 3",
    "2019-12-31": "something 4",
}

dates = dict(
    sorted(dates.items(), key=lambda item: datetime(*map(int, item[0].split("-"))))
)
```

However, with the way that your dates are formatted, you can just sort normally without issues, hence @Axe319's solution in the comments works perfectly:

```
dates = {
        "2020-01-01": "something 1",
        "2019-04-20": "something 2",
        "2020-03-15": "something 3",
        "2019-12-31": "something 4",
    }

dates = dict(sorted(dates.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
d={

"dates":
    {
      "2020-01-01": "something 1",
      "2019-04-20": "something 2",
      "2020-03-15": "something 3",
      "2019-12-31": "something 4"
    }
}

for w in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=False):
    print(d[w])
inv_map = {v: k for k, v in d[w].items()}
print(inv_map)
for w in sorted(inv_map, key=inv_map.get, reverse=True):
    print(inv_map[w])
```

Output:

```
{'2020-01-01': 'something 1', '2019-04-20': 'something 2', '2020-03-15': 'something 3', '2019-12-31': 'something 4'}
{'something 1': '2020-01-01', 'something 2': '2019-04-20', 'something 3': '2020-03-15', 'something 4': '2019-12-31'}
2020-03-15
2020-01-01
2019-12-31
2019-04-20
```